# Audio Events in Jquery on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm having issues with jquery's on() binding function and the audio element. I have dynamically generated audio elements on my page, so I can't just do `$('audio').on('ended', function(e){})`. Instead, what I do, and what works for me with every other element is create an on() event for the container that isn't dynamically generated. In this case, I do something like this:

```
$('.charts-container').on('ended', 'audio', function(e){}).
```

Which doesn't trigger the function like `$('audio').on('ended'... )` does. What gives?

Comment: Media events dont bubble - you have to bind to the element directly

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291651/why-dont-audio-and-video-events-bubble