# 2 audio sounds and I want to play one HTML5 audio element at a time

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Question:  I have 2 audio sounds and I want to play one HTML5 audio element at a time.

Similar Post:  [Play one HTML audio element at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719550/play-one-html-audio-element-at-a-time).

I saw a similar post to my question. However, as a JavaScript beginner I did not understand the code. So I tried a simpler way so I can understand, but is not working.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

HTML5 code: (For this example only I used the same audio source as a previous post:  http://jsfiddle.net/RE006/8djstmvy/

```
<div>
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<audio id="sound1" src=http://geo-samples.beatport.com/lofi/5005876.LOFI.mp3 controls="controls" preload="none">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Example 2</h2>
<audio id="sound2" src=http://geo-samples.beatport.com/lofi/5005933.LOFI.mp3 controls="controls" preload="none">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
}

var sound1_click = function() {
//starts playing
$("sound1").play ();
//pause playing
$("sound2").pause();
}

var sound2_click = function() {
//starts playing
$("sound2").play ();
//pause playing
$("sound1").pause();
}

window.onload = function () {
$("sound1").onclick = sound1_click;
$("sound2").onclick = sound2_click;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are listing to `click` event, when you should be listening to `play` event, also for some reason, `window.onload` does not work properly in jsfiddle, so replace

```
window.onload = function () {
    $("sound1").onclick = sound1_click;
    $("sound2").onclick = sound2_click;
}
```

with

```
$("sound1").onplay = sound1_click;
$("sound2").onplay = sound2_click;
```

#### [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8djstmvy/1/)

or you can simply generalize it by:

```
var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
for(var i=0; i<audios.length;i++)    audios[i].onplay = pauseAllAudios.bind(null, audios[i]);

function pauseAllAudios(audio){
    for(var i=0; i<audios.length;i++)
        if(audios[i]!=audio)    audios[i].pause();    
};
```

#### [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8djstmvy/6/)

Comment: Just to confirm, I should include the window.onload in the js file.?

Comment: yes, I guess it is safer that way, but don't why it doesn't work in jsfiddle, probably because this whole bock of code is loaded within iframe.

Comment: Could I also write it this way too? jsfiddle.net/RE006/8djstmvy/4
I don't understand why this one isn't working.

Comment: @user5117220 I am not sure as to why you are using `!`, but check my updated answer, it has generalized way of doing it.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to generalize it, but ! was the wrong choice. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The codes works.  Last question why do you put null in  pauseAllAudios.bind(null, audios[i]);?

Comment: I am using `null` as the `this` object value within function ` pauseAllAudios` since I am not using the `this` object anywhere inside the function, the first parameter value could have been anything else, it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.