# How to bind fullscreen event in HTML5 video element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, video

I am currently using following binding in **angularJS** controller. I am having problem of the event being bound multiple times. Is there a way to bind events to a specific element?

Let's say I have 2 videos like this:

```
<video id="video1"></video>
<video id="video2"></video>
```

**JS**

*This works*

```
$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function (e){
    //Do stuff like unmute video
});
```

*This doesn't work. I thought this should work.*

```
$(document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0]).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function (e){
    //Do stuff like unmute video
});
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with plain JS? `$(document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0])`? Why not just `$('video:eq(0)')`?

Comment: I don't know. Just trying out different stuff and getting messed up, but it has nothing to do with the question...

Comment: Just a thought, how about using ```e.target```? would that bee the video node? something like this: ```$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function (e){
    var $videoElement = $(e.target); /* do things with video element that linked to screenchange event */
});```  The reason could be similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291651/why-dont-audio-and-video-events-bubble