# Audio event does not trigger jQuery on play event

Tags: jquery, event-handling, html5-audio, jquery-events

I try to execute a function on an audio `play` event :

```
jQuery('audio').on('play', function () { /* ... */ });
```

But my element is not present at the time this function is executed, so it's not selected. Instead I have the habit to use a different syntax when I need to trigger event for dynamic added content :

```
jQuery('.constant-container').on('play', 'audio', function () {
    /* ... */ 
});
```

Where the `.constant-container` does not change.
But this solution does not seems to work, the audio element does not get any `click` event either.

Here is a [link to the bin](http://jsbin.com/duwixekeko/1/edit?html,js,output).

The first 4 audio handle correctly the event, but not the 4 last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently media events( those specifically belonging to *audio* or *video* like `play`, `pause`, `timeupdate`, etc) do not get bubbled. you can find the explanation for that in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291651/why-dont-audio-and-video-events-bubble).

So using their solution, I captured the `play` event,

```
jQuery.createEventCapturing(['play']);  
jQuery('body').on('play', 'audio', function(){... // now this would work.
```

#### [JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/vucobezoxe/1/edit?html,js,output)

the code for event capturing( taken from the other SO answer):

```
    jQuery.createEventCapturing = (function () {
        var special = jQuery.event.special;
        return function (names) {
            if (!document.addEventListener) {
                return;
            }
            if (typeof names == 'string') {
                names = [names];
            }
            jQuery.each(names, function (i, name) {
                var handler = function (e) {
                    e = jQuery.event.fix(e);

                    return jQuery.event.dispatch.call(this, e);
                };
                special[name] = special[name] || {};
                if (special[name].setup || special[name].teardown) {
                    return;
                }
                jQuery.extend(special[name], {
                    setup: function () {
                        this.addEventListener(name, handler, true);
                    },
                    teardown: function () {
                        this.removeEventListener(name, handler, true);
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    })();
```