Is it possible to have the play event not directly on a video, but on a document?
I want to listen to any play event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event
From the docs the listener must be attached to a video.
And the following didn't work:
document.addEventListener("play", (event) => {
    // do something when some video starts playing
});

Because I want to do some generic actions when any video starts playing in the page, so I don't want to attach listener to every video (so to use delegation)
The reason I need to do it is because I have custom controls, and I want to be able to change the buttons (toggle play/pause for example) whenever a video is played/paused, without having the listener on the video itself every time

As the MDN docs you linked mention, the play event doesn’t bubble, so you’ll need to use a capturing event listener instead by passing a third argument to addEventListener.


document.addEventListener('play', () => {
  console.log('play');
}, true);
#video {
  max-width: 100%;
}
<video id="video" controls src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"></video>




It works, and when I add the event to the listener: document.addEventListener('play', (event) => {..}, true) it even gets the video as the event.target. Thank you!

now I'm curious, why do certain events don't bubble, like the one above? When there can be situations, just like the one above where it's needed? So why not make them bubble in the first place instead of using useCapture, which eventually gets the job done as well, just with extra code?

What do you mean “eventually”? , true isn’t a lot of extra code, and the capture phase happens downward before the upward bubble phase. Anyway, there are things like the mouseenter event where a reasonable default is to care only when it happens directly to the element you attached it to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291651/why-dont-audio-and-video-events-bubble
